# How do I allow a checkbox value through AJAX(not changing it) Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So I basically want the current_user to be able to blacklist users. So I created a search for the users and a form which gets the selected checkboxes and blacklists or whitelists them. The search is done through AJAX but the problem is that after the search is done the checkbox ( if checked ) becomes unchecked. How do I keep the checkbox value as it is. I want to be able to pass the value through AJAX, any idea on how I can do that:

Controller:

```
   def show
     @b_page = BPage.find(params[:id])
     if params[:search221]
       @users = User.search(params[:search221])
       respond_to do |format|
        format.js
       end
     else
      @users = User.all
     end
  end
```

Show Page:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal5541" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <h1> Privacy Settings</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_tag b_page_path, :method => 'get', :id => "users_search", :remote => true do %>
          <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :search221, params[:search221], class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Search for users'%>
          <div class="text-center">
             <%= submit_tag "Search", class:"btn btn-primary"%>
          </div>
        <% end %>

        <%= form_tag({:controller=>"b_pages",:action=>"change_privacy_settings"} , method: :put) do %>
             <ul id="yolo"> <%= render "losers"%> </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= submit_tag "Update Privacy Settings"%>
        <% end %>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

losers partial:

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <div id="<%= user.id%>">
       <div class="panel">
           <!-- The checkbox-->
           <%= check_box_tag "user_ids[]", user.id%> 
           <%= image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb))%>
          <%= user.username %>
       </div>
     </div>
  <% end %>      
   <div class="center">
       <%= will_paginate @users, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails  %>
   </div>
```

show.js.erb:

```
$("#yolo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'losers', :locals => {:users=> @users}) %>")
```

How do I not loose the checkbox value(losers partial) even after the search?

Comment: usually people store filters value within url as parameters. So visiting url gives the same type of result no matter the computer (which would be session based). `https://www.example.com/q=shoes&sort_by=prices&order=desc`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer the current_user could check multiple users. The number of checkboxes could even go upto 15 or 20.... I don't think storing the params in the url would be a very good idea unless it's for the add to blacklist method but not for the rendering

Comment: ok so other way is to keep record of user preference in session that is updated with ajax, and then each time rendering search page, set checkbox value attribute using values from session